# Erro ao tentar utilizar métodos ArrayList (símbolo não reconhecido)

Tags: java-8, arraylist

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu simplesmente não consigo utilizar nenhum método da classe ArrayList (sempre dá erro de compilação) e não faço ideia do porque. Estou cometendo algum erro de sintaxe? Não consegui nenhuma resposta pesquisando na internet. Coloquei fotos para demonstrar exatamente o problema. É como se ele não reconhecesse o "."

As linhas comentadas são porque eu ia testar os métodos da classe (ainda estou aprendendo a programar), mas todos davam erro quando eu tentava executar, então comentei as linhas para deixar o prompt de comando mais enxuto. O erro era exatamente o mesmo em todas as linhas (o demonstrado na imagem).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayList {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        ArrayList cores = new ArrayList();
        cores.add("Branco");

    }
}
```

Comment: Adicione o código em texto, ao inves de imagem, pois isso atrapalha quem for te ajudar a testar o código. Leia [**isso**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/28595)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse erro está ocorrendo porque você nomeou a sua classe como `ArrayList`. Dessa forma, o método que se tenta evocar é um método da sua classe `ArrayList` chamado `add(String s)` que não existe, ao invés de evocar o método da class `java.util.ArrayList`. Mude o nome da sua classe para algo como `ArrayListTest` e isso resolverá o problema.

Além disso, você pode parametrizar o `ArrayList` para garantir que o único tipo de objeto que será inserido na sua `ArrayList` seja do tipo `String`, ficando assim:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> cores = new ArrayList<>();
        cores.add("branco");
    }
}
```

Uma outra forma de resolver esse problema de colisão de nomes, que pode ser utilizado quando você não pode alterar o nome das classes, é utilizar o [Fully Qualified name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name):

```
public class ArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.ArrayList<String> cores = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        cores.add("branco");
    }
}
```